# how to trigger email sending automatically from the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm battling with some problem here. I have a message in my mysql  database that I want to send based on the scheduled date is there any way to do this : that when is the exact date  the server should send the maill by itself, OR is there anyway to make a page load itself everyday  without my access to send the email(if no one visit the site).    Thanks. I'm using php and mysql db. I have scheduleddate  column in my database

Comment: Use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) on *nix or [task scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) when on windows to run a php script that you prepare.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [cron job](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to call a script which checks the database at a set interval (perhaps once per hour) and then have that script pull out the relevant messages and sends them.

The cron for that would look something like:

```
0 * * * * /path/to/email/script.php
```

This script could then query the database and send those messages which need sending. Of course you could set this to run every single minute (`* * * * *`), but I'd be very wary of having any script run every single minute!

This isn't really ideal thought, and instead you should look at using some form of queue management. If you take a look at [queues.io](http://queues.io/) you can find lots of info on various popular queue projects projects.

I also found this post on [setting up background jobs using resque](http://kamisama.me/2012/10/09/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-1-introduction/) very helpful!

Of course how you integrate such a system is very much dependent on your codebase and your environment.

Some frameworks have this kinda functionality integrated very well, I have worked with [Laravel 4's queue component](http://laravel.com/docs/queues) quite a lot and it really does make it very easy to work with..

In reality many people just end up using a cron/script combo to do the job, but it's important to know there are other (better) ways to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your time I will take a time to read about cron nw. I dnt tink my server has this features.  Is this a script or a settings on someone hosting host

Comment: You'd need to configure this from your hosting control panel, without knowing more about your hosting setup it's difficult for me to help further. Can you tell me about your hosting setup?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this without killing your CPU utilization is by scheduling it via a scheduled cron task on your server. Write your code to send the email, then add that page to a daily cron in your server's Admin Control Panel.